# Infer does not satisfy type constraints?

Tags: typescript

I was solving typescript challenges and ran into Reverse challenge. This was my [solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShBuEBOBnCAeAKlCAPYEAdgCYpQrBICWhA5gNoC6AfFALxTZ4Eln0B0gmgDNksCBRz4ipcpRoNGAGigixAGQCGFRlAD8UeloorB-OIlQY4FZroBch3QChQkKLnbjLadPQDkAIz+Sv4ATCH+AMz+LM4A9PEeXvQARFGpKqlhmVCpgamMQA):

```
type Reverse<T extends string[]> = 
  T extends [...infer Rest extends string[], infer Last] ? 
    [Last, ...Reverse<Rest>] : []
```

Everything works, but if I don't explicitly re-constrain `Rest` to `string[]` and just let the compiler infer it, as in:

```
type Reverse<T extends string[]> = 
  T extends [...infer Rest, infer Last] ? 
    [Last, ...Reverse<Rest>] : []
```

I get this error:

```
Type 'Rest' does not satisfy the constraint 'string[]'.
Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Why is the type of `Rest` `unknown[]`, when we constrain `T` to be `string[]`?  Is this normal behaviour or am I missing something?

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShBuEBOBnCAeAKlCAPYEAdgCYpQrBICWhA5gNoC6AfFALxTZ4Eln0B0gmgDNksCBQA0UEWIAyAQwqMoAfij1FUqIP5xEqDHArMVALg0qAUKEhRc7cQbTp6AcgCMbyW4BM3twBmNxYrAHow+0d6ACJAmOkY3wSoGI8YxiA)

Comment: What's your TS version? The code works for me https://tsplay.dev/N731GN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a missing feature of TypeScript, requested at [microsoft/TypeScript#51108](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51108).  For whatever reason, currently types inferred by `infer` tend to lose known constraints.  According to [a comment in that issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51108#issuecomment-1439826624), it's possible a lot of real world code actually *depends* on this constraint loss, and that enforcing this will end up breaking things.  But it's not clear that this has actually been investigated.  So, until and unless this feature is implemented, `infer Rest` will end up inferring a type wider than you'd like.

Anyway, before TypeScript 4.7 introduced [`extends` constraints on `infer` type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables) such as `infer Rest extends string[]`, the situation was significantly worse, since you'd need to add a new conditional type to re-constrain things like

```
type Reverse<T extends string[]> = 
  T extends [...infer Rest, infer Last] ?
    Rest extends string[] ? [Last, ...Reverse<Rest>] : never : []
```

And therefore

```
type Reverse<T extends string[]> = 
  T extends [...infer Rest extends string[], infer Last] ? 
    [Last, ...Reverse<Rest>] : []
```

is an improvement.  Still, it would be nice if someday the second `extends string[]` could be dropped entirely.  If you care, you might want to go to that GitHub issue and give it a , as enough community demand for it could increase the likelihood of its implementation.  Of course a single upvote will have a negligible effect and even hundreds might not do anything.  So for the foreseeable future you should probably just make do with your current version, and at least be comfortable knowing it's the best you can do.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShBuEBOBnCAeAKlCAPYEAdgCYpQrBICWhA5gNoC6AfFALxTZ4Eln0B0gmgDNksCBQA0UEWIAyAQwqMoAfgBQUcRRz4ipcpRoMVqqPUVSog-nESoMcCsxUAuKIQRj3TdeqA)